# is it possible to replace existing antenna with a high gain antenna?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have added an external wifi antenna using [this](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/intel-nuc-poor-wifi-external-antenna-mod.4071908/) guide. I have used a 2 db antenna and the wifi adapter is [Intel AC-3165](https://www.intel.in/content/www/in/en/products/wireless/wireless-products/dual-band-wireless-ac-3165.html). The range is similar as when I was using an Internal antenna. I am using the device to create a wireless access point on the 2.4 Ghz band.

Is it possible to replace the antenna with a higher gain antenna(say 6dbi)?
Will the wifi adapter be able to drive the larger antenna?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that an antenna is just a passive piece of metal, specially shaped to help steer the radio energy it is emitting or receiving. Antenna gain is also called “directional gain”, and is a measure of how well the metal’s shape steers radio energy in a particular direction, compared to a theoretical antenna that radiates energy evenly in all directions in a perfect sphere (this is called an “isotropic” antenna). This is why the directional gain of an antenna is measured in “dBi”: Those are decibels of directional gain relative to an isotropic antenna.

A so-called “omnidirectional” antenna is not a spherical radiator like an isotropic. Instead it only cares about a single plane and tries to radiate energy in a 360 degree disk in that one plane. Think of taking a water balloon and squishing it between a book and a table. By reducing the height of the balloon and making it less of a sphere and more of a disk, it gains distance at the edges of the disk.

So, yes, any radio can “drive” any antenna, and yes, you could get a 6dBi omni. But beware that when you have antennas with directional gain, you have to pay attention to how you point them, so that you’re pointing their gain direction in the direction you want it to go.

An omni on an AP IS great for covering space on a single floor, from the center of the space. If you’re trying to cover a 2-story space with a single AP, or if your AP is not in the center of your space, then there might be a better choice than a 6dBi omnidirectional antenna.